# Sql select duplicate rows multiple columns

Tags: sql

I would like to have a query that returns one row for each `ComuterName`.  The row should contain the queried application along with its version.  My current query of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  dbo.v_R_System.Name0 [ComputerName],
  dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 [App],
  dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0
FROM
  dbo.v_R_System 
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS
    ON dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_R_User
    ON dbo.v_R_System.User_Name0 = dbo.v_R_User.User_Name0
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM
    ON dbo.v_R_System.Name0 = dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
  INNER JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS
    ON dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
WHERE
  dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%MS Word%'
  OR dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Adobe Reader%'
  OR dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Flash Player%'
```

Returns this:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ ComputerName ║        App         ║ Version ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════╣
║ PC1          ║ MS Word            ║ 12      ║
║ PC1          ║ Adobe Reader       ║ 10.0.10 ║
║ PC1          ║ Adobe Flash Player ║ 15.1    ║
║ PC2          ║ MS Word            ║ 15      ║
║ PC2          ║ Adobe Reader       ║ 11.0.07 ║
║ PC2          ║ Adobe Flash Player ║ 16      ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

I would like to return the info in this fashion:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ ComputerName ║  App1   ║ App1Ver ║     App2     ║ App2Ver ║        App3        ║ App3Ver ║
╠══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════╬═════════╣
║ PC1          ║ MS Word ║      12 ║ Adobe Reader ║ 10.0.10 ║ Adobe Flash Player ║ 15.1    ║
║ PC2          ║ MS Word ║      15 ║ Adobe Reader ║ 11.0.07 ║ Adobe Flash Player ║ 16      ║
╚══════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

This database is stored on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What database are you using?  This concept is known as PIVOT and the syntax may be different depending on your product.

Comment: This database is stored on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case based aggregation`, there is another problem with `like` here as you are using % wild card the index won't be used and it will be slower on large data set

It would be better to use have a group id column and have a mapping table between application name and group and use group id in the query.

```
SELECT 
  dbo.v_R_System.Name0 [ComputerName],
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%MS Word%' then 'MS Word' end ) as App1,
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%MS Word%' then dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0 end ) as App1Ver
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Adobe Reader%' then 'Adobe Reader' end ) as App1,
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Adobe Reader%' then dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0 end ) as App2Ver
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Flash Player%' then 'Flash Player' end ) as App1,
  max(case when dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Flash Player%' then dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0 end ) as App3Ver

FROM
  dbo.v_R_System 
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS
    ON dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_R_User
    ON dbo.v_R_System.User_Name0 = dbo.v_R_User.User_Name0
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM
    ON dbo.v_R_System.Name0 = dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
  INNER JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS
    ON dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
group by dbo.v_R_System.Name0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, radar.  That is exactly what I was looking for .  I'm not too concerned about the query performance as it will not executed frequently.